# Eigen decomposition power method

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

im looking through some lecture notes and im not understanding the part of the right hand side.
So i believe that the lecture is talking about recovering the largest Eigenvector and value from repeated application of A with first a random vector and then the resulting vector after. The vector yM converges to an Eigen vector.
However, im troubled by the explaination on the right hand side, it seems that the resulting vectors are written as a summation of Eigenvectors multiplied by Eigenvalues and constants

Is there such a result that a vector Y can be written as a summation EigenvectorsxEigenvaluesxconstant of another matrix? Im new to matrices, thank you

My attempt is understanding this is that
A = VAV^-1
y1=Ay0 = VAV^-1y0
y2=Ay1 = VA^2V^-1y0
y3=Ay2 = VA^3V^-1y0

Why is this equivalent to summation of the Eigen vectors and values?

[image]

Comment: OK nevermind i think i get it

Comment: Ok i dont undersand, why does the summation of EigenVectorxEigenvalue give the output vector?

Comment: Hi, anyone can give me help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if you aren't looking for a long explanation, but it might help other people who wander across this question.

Most of the time, the eigenvectors of a matrix will form another basis for the vector space you're working with.
Generally, if you're working in $\mathbb{R}^2$, say, you're used to working with the standard basis, the unit horizontal and vertical vector. What this means is that any vector in the plane can be expressed as a weighted combination of $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$. The coordinates of a vector is just its 'horizontal' and 'vertical' components.

But there's no reason to stick to this basis. You could use any two different vectors just as well. You could take $\hat{u} =\hat{i}+\hat{j}$ and $\hat{v} =\hat{i} - \hat{j}$ and use that as a basis. Then the point that you would normally call $(0, -1)$ in the $i, j$ basis would now be called $(-1/2, 1/2)$ in the $u, v$ basis. And so on.

Now coming to eigenvectors. The whole deal with eigenvectors of a matrix is that they help you understand what a matrix is really doing: when a matrix is applied to one of its eigenvectors, it just stretches it or squashes it, without doing anything funny like changing its direction. The amount of stretching or squashing each eigenvector undergoes is termed its eigenvalue. So how do we use this to help understand the action of a matrix on some random vector?

We express that vector in terms of the eigenvectors of the matrix. In other words, let's take the eigenvectors of our matrix and use them as our basis. Then the random vector we're looking at can be written as a linear combination of those eigenvectors, i.e. as a sum over all those eigenvectors, each with some constant attached to it. This is no different from when we express a vector in terms of its 'horizontal' and 'vertical' components, only that our definitions of 'horizontal' and 'vertical' here have changed direction. In two dimensions, for clarity, this means that if the matrix $A$ has eigenvectors $x_1$ and $x_2$, then given a random vector $y$, we can definitely find some sort of constants $c_q$ and $c_2$ such that $y=c_1x_1+c_2x_2$. That makes sense so far?

Now we're ready to apply the matrix to the vector. Well, since the matrix is a linear operator, we can apply it separately to each of the different components of the vector, and add them up at the end. But wait! Since we made sure the components are in terms of the eigenvector basis, we know exactly what the matrix will do to each of those components - it will just multiply them by the corresponding eigenvalues! Nothing else, nothing funny going on here. So basically, we know that if the eigenvalues of $x_1$ and $x_2$ are $k_1$ and $k_2$ respectively, then $Ax_1=k_1x_1$, and so on.

So what does that mean for our vector? Clearly, $Ay=A(c_1x_1)+A(c_2x_2)=c_1k_1x_1+c_2k_2x_2$.
And if we apply A again, i.e. calculate $A^2y$, you can see how each component will be multiplied by the eigenvalue again, yielding $c_1k_1^2x_1+c_2k_2^2x_2$. And you could keep applying $A$ again and again, say, $m$ times, and clearly, you'd end up with $A^my=c_1k_1^mx_1+c_2k_2^mx_2$.

Now it should be easy to see how, if one of the eigenvalues is bigger than the others, than after building up a big exponent, it'll grow super fast and the other components will become negligible in contrast, so we can essentially drop those and be left with only the component corresponding to maximum eigenvalue.

Hope that helps, please tell me if something is unclear!